# Passing Data Array from Controller to View Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to simplify my menu, that i will pass into my view, the problem is menu and submenu is not active. This is my controller:

```
parent::__construct();
    $this->menu = array(
      'menu'    => 'definition',
      'submenu' => 'workplace'
    );
```

And i have this in my controller method:

```
$data = array(
    $this->menu, // menu is right here
    'list_workplace_type' => get_wp_type()->result_array()
  );
var_dump($data);die;
$this->load->view('wp', $data);
```

And the result is like below:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'menu' => 'definition'
      'submenu' => 'workplace'
  'list_workplace_type' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'szWorkplaceTypeName' => 'Kantor Pusat'
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'szWorkplaceTypeName' => 'Kantor Cabang'
```

What I expected is more like this:

```
array (size=2)
  'menu' => 'definition'
  'submenu' => 'workplace'
  'list_workplace_type' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'workplaceTypeName' => 'Kantor Pusat'
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'workplaceTypeName' => 'Kantor Cabang'
```

I used *array_push()* but still doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you're trying to add 'list_workplace_type' as another key in the Menu array so you need to change this

```
$data = array(
    $this->menu, // menu is right here
    'list_workplace_type' => get_wp_type()->result_array()
  );
```

to

```
$data = $this->menu['list_workplace_type'] = get_wp_type()->result_array();
```

and then you can pass to view

```
$this->load->view('wp', $data);
```

Comment: I will prefer this answer. It is most probably correct way to get array you the user wants.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to assume that **get_wp_type()** is a helper function.

You have used **$result->result_array()** which will give you the observed result.

What you need to use is **$result->row_array()** which will give you the result you are expecting.

So

```
$data = array(
    $this->menu, // menu is right here
    'list_workplace_type' => get_wp_type()->result_array()
  );
```

becomes

```
$data = array(
    $this->menu, // menu is right here
    'list_workplace_type' => get_wp_type()->row_array()
  );
```

Go and look them up in the codeigniter user guide. It's a good habit to get into.